# How to decrypt a columnar transposition cipher

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

My question is not one of coding per say, but of understanding the algorithm.

Conceptually I understand how the column transposition deciphers text with a constant key value for example 10.

My confusion occurs, when the key is a permutation. For example `key = [2,4,6,8,10,1,3,5,7,9]` and a message like `"XOV EK HLYR NUCO HEEEWADCRETL CEEOACT KD"`. The part where I'm confused is writing the cipher text into rows, then permuting the row according to the key.

Can someone please provide some clarification on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Once you know the number of rows and columns, you can write the ciphertext into the rows, then permute the rows according to the key. Please correct if my explanation is wrong.  The plain text is "execlent work you have cracked the code"

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the key becomes an ordering for every `x` letters in the cipher, `x` is the length of the key. In your example case, the key is 10 in length, so you arrange the first 10 letters by their corresponding order number.

That is the explanation, here is some code I wrote to arrange the cipher in proper order using the key:

```
import math

moves = [2,4,6,8,10,1,3,5,7,9]
msg = "XOV EK HLYR NUCO HEEEWADCRETL CEEOACT KD"

decrypted = list(msg)

for i, letter in enumerate(msg):
    moves_index = i % len(moves)

    index = (math.floor(i / len(moves)) * len(moves)) + moves[moves_index]

    decrypted[index - 1] = letter

    print(str.format('{}, at index {}, goes in destination index {} (letter number {})', letter, i, index - 1, index))

print(''.join(decrypted))
```

This prints out each step so that you can verify it against what you would do by hand:

```
X, at index 0, goes in destination index 1 (letter number 2)
O, at index 1, goes in destination index 3 (letter number 4)
V, at index 2, goes in destination index 5 (letter number 6)
 , at index 3, goes in destination index 7 (letter number 8)
E, at index 4, goes in destination index 9 (letter number 10)
K, at index 5, goes in destination index 0 (letter number 1)
 , at index 6, goes in destination index 2 (letter number 3)
H, at index 7, goes in destination index 4 (letter number 5)
L, at index 8, goes in destination index 6 (letter number 7)
Y, at index 9, goes in destination index 8 (letter number 9)
R, at index 10, goes in destination index 11 (letter number 12)
 , at index 11, goes in destination index 13 (letter number 14)
N, at index 12, goes in destination index 15 (letter number 16)
U, at index 13, goes in destination index 17 (letter number 18)
C, at index 14, goes in destination index 19 (letter number 20)
O, at index 15, goes in destination index 10 (letter number 11)
 , at index 16, goes in destination index 12 (letter number 13)
H, at index 17, goes in destination index 14 (letter number 15)
E, at index 18, goes in destination index 16 (letter number 17)
E, at index 19, goes in destination index 18 (letter number 19)
E, at index 20, goes in destination index 21 (letter number 22)
W, at index 21, goes in destination index 23 (letter number 24)
A, at index 22, goes in destination index 25 (letter number 26)
D, at index 23, goes in destination index 27 (letter number 28)
C, at index 24, goes in destination index 29 (letter number 30)
R, at index 25, goes in destination index 20 (letter number 21)
E, at index 26, goes in destination index 22 (letter number 23)
T, at index 27, goes in destination index 24 (letter number 25)
L, at index 28, goes in destination index 26 (letter number 27)
 , at index 29, goes in destination index 28 (letter number 29)
C, at index 30, goes in destination index 31 (letter number 32)
E, at index 31, goes in destination index 33 (letter number 34)
E, at index 32, goes in destination index 35 (letter number 36)
O, at index 33, goes in destination index 37 (letter number 38)
A, at index 34, goes in destination index 39 (letter number 40)
C, at index 35, goes in destination index 30 (letter number 31)
T, at index 36, goes in destination index 32 (letter number 33)
 , at index 37, goes in destination index 34 (letter number 35)
K, at index 38, goes in destination index 36 (letter number 37)
D, at index 39, goes in destination index 38 (letter number 39)
```

However this prints, finally: `KX OHVL YEOR  HNEUECREEWTALD CCCTE EKODA`, which does not match your proposed solution: `execlent work you have cracked the code` (ignoring case, obviously). Not sure what the discrepancy is...